# Query para unir tabelas específicas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, query

Preciso unir 3 tabelas diferentes.
Porém o resultado que quero é: Quando existir a referência ele deve unir, quando não existir deve mostrar em branco ou NULL.

Minha estrutura:

**Tabela contato**

```
+------+------------+
|  ID  |    Nome    |
+------+------------+
|  1   | Contato #1 |
+------+------------+
|  2   | Contato #2 |
+------+------------+
|  3   | Contato #3 |
+------+------------+
|  4   | Contato #4 |
+------+------------+
|  5   | Contato #5 |
+------+------------+
```

**Tabela contato_email**

```
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
|  ID  | id_contato |           email             |
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
|  1   |      1     | contato1_email1@exemplo.com |
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
|  2   |      2     | contato2_email1@exemplo.com |
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
|  3   |      2     | contato2_email2@exemplo.com |
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
```

Eu fiz esse inner join:

```
select * 
from contato
inner join contato_email on (contato.id_contato = contato_email.id_contato)
```

Mas com isso ele me retorna somente os usuários que tem um email.
Observe que um usuário pode ter mais de um email associado.
Quero buscar todos os contatos e se tiver email eu devo unir os dados.

```
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
|  ID  |    Nome    |          email              |
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
|  1   | Contato #1 | contato1_email1@exemplo.com |
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
|  2   | Contato #2 | contato2_email1@exemplo.com |
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
|  2   | Contato #2 | contato2_email1@exemplo.com |
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
|  3   | Contato #3 |                             |
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
|  4   | Contato #4 |                             |
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
|  5   | Contato #5 |                             |
+------+------------+-----------------------------+
```

**Esse é o retorno desejado.**
Obrigado.

Comment: Tentou com `left join` ou não serve? Relacionado: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/91)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente substituir o Inner por LEFT JOIN

```
select * 
from contato
left join contato_email on (contato.id_contato = contato_email.id_contato)
```

Comment: Nossa. Estava apanhando tem 30 min nisso --' Obrigado haha.

Comment: De nada! É normal, apanho ás vezes também!